# java client and server chat system

Tags: java

i have little problem when i creating client and server chat system client doesn't read characters i am using bufferedinput stream

Comment: Can you add the relevant bits of code from the client and server?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are using a BufferedOutputStream or BufferedWriter and you haven't flush()ed the stream so the data is just sitting in the buffer on the sending side.

Comment: My guess is the hamsters aren't running fast enough to transfer the data.